# Strange behavior on Hadoop's reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple class called `Pair` that implements `org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable`. It contains two fields and is used as a Value in the MapReduce process.

For each key, I want to find the pair with the largest value of one of Pair's fields (preco). In the reducer the following code produces the expected result:

```
float max = 0;
String country = "";
for (Pair p : values){
    if (p.getPreco().get() > max)
    {
        max = p.getPreco().get();
        country = p.getPais().toString();
    }
}
context.write(key, new Pair(new FloatWritable(max), new Text(country)));
```

The following code, on the other hand, does not:

```
Pair max = new Pair();
for (Pair p : values)
    if (p.getPreco().get() > max.getPreco().get())
        max = p;

context.write(key, max);
```

The second code produces, for each key, the last value that is associated to it in the input file and not the highest value.

Is there a reason for this apparently strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this problem because the reducer is reusing objects, so its iterator over the values is always passing you the same object. Thus this code:

`max = p;`

Will always refer the current value of `p`. You need to copy the the data into `max` for this to work properly and not reference the object. This is why the first version of your code is working.

Usually in Hadoop I would implement a `.set()` method on a custom writable, this is a common pattern you will see. So your `Pair` class might look a bit like (its missing the interface methods etc):

```
public class Pair implements Writable {

    public FloatWritable max = new FloatWritable();
    public Text country = new Text();

    public void set(Pair p) {
        this.max.set(p.max.get());
        this.country.set(p.country);
    }
}
```

And you would change your code to:

```
Pair max = new Pair();
for (Pair p : values) {
    if (p.max().get() > max.max.get()) {
        max.set(p);
    }
}
context.write(key, max);
```

I haven't created `getters` in `Pair` so the code is changed slightly to directly access the public class variables.